# Spacing of text within a table cell

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I am inserting the following text inside the cell of a table

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex, final]{graphicx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{marvosym} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{color}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}

\definecolor{female}{rgb}{1.0,0.2,0.2}
\definecolor{male} {rgb}{0.2,0.2,1.0}

\newcommand{\hgF}[1]{
\begin{description} \parskip0pt \parsep0pt 
\itemsep0pt \partopsep0pt
\item[{\color{female}{\Female}}]%
{\color{female}{{\Large {\bf #1}}}}%
\end{description}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{| p{0.4cm} | p{3.5cm} | p{1.8cm} | p{3.2cm} | p{3.5cm} | p{1.8cm} | p{3.2cm} | p{1.8cm} | p{3.2cm} |}
\hline 
1 & \hgF{Louise Get} & 01/01/1847 & Revel (Haute-Garonne) & \hgF{Alphonse Martin} & 20/03/1865 & Revel (Haute-Garonne) & 07/10/1951 & Revel (Haute-Garonne) \\ [5pt]
\hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

I end up with way too much white space before and after the "FirstName LastName" text. Which are the dimensions controlling this additional spacing?

Secondary question, how do I (simply) avoid stretching the other text across the column width (hence the \flushleft command I had earlier!!).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show a complete MWE?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the `flushleft` (which isn't doing much other than affecting the vertical space)

Comment: removed the \flushleft (left-over from previous trial and error). Spacing before and after still excessive!

Answer (score 6):

`\Large` is a switch, `\bf` is deprecated and `\color{female}` doesn't take an argument too. So you need

```
\newcommand{\hgF}[1]{%
\begin{description} [nosep,labelwidth=0.75em,leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep,
                           before=\vspace{-0.7\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
\item[\color{female}\Female]%
{\color{female}\Large\bfseries#1}%
\end{description}%
}
```

Further, you may need to have `\raggedright` columns with

```
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

With this we have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex, final]{graphicx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}

\definecolor{female}{rgb}{1.0,0.2,0.2}
\definecolor{male} {rgb}{0.2,0.2,1.0}

\newcommand{\hgF}[1]{%
\begin{description} [nosep,labelwidth=0.75em,leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep,
                                 before=\vspace{-0.7\baselineskip},after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
\item[\color{female}\Female]%
{\color{female}\Large\bfseries#1}%
\end{description}%
}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{| P{0.4cm} | P{3.5cm} | P{1.8cm} | P{3.2cm} | P{3.5cm} | P{1.8cm} | P{3.2cm} | P{1.8cm} | P{3.2cm} |}
\hline
1 & \hgF{Louise Get} & 01/01/1847 & Revel (Haute-Garonne) & \hgF{Alphonse Martin} & 20/03/1865 & Revel (Haute-Garonne) & 07/10/1951 & Revel (Haute-Garonne) \\ [5pt]
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, progress, but I still would like to reduce significantly the space above and below the "Louise Get" and Alphonse Martin" cells. This is part of a long table which would stretch way too much with those settings.

Comment: Yes, just like that. I now need to "understand" the logic behind these parameters. I guess this is a classical case of RTFM!!
Thanks anyway!!

Comment: One last question : how do I get the "Martin" to align with the "Alphonse". I tried several things redefining a new environment and resetting \leftmargin to no avail!! Thanks

Comment: @Henri You have to adjust `labelwidth=0.75em,leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep`. See the edit.